# GS query record based of next records value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the previous `Approved` date right before the first found `Requeue` date. Doing this in pure SQL is not an issue but google sheets is making this difficult. Any ideas?

```
ColumnA     ColumnB ColumnC
8/20/2020   Create  00310913
8/25/2020   Edit    00310913
8/26/2020   Approve 00310913
8/26/2020   Approve 00310913 <------ The `Approve` record I want
8/26/2020   Requeue 00310913 <------ First `Requeue` date
8/27/2020   Edit    00310913
8/27/2020   Approve 00310913
8/27/2020   Approve 00310913
8/27/2020   Requeue 00310913
8/27/2020   Approve 00310913
8/28/2020   Requeue 00310913
8/31/2020   Issue   00310913
9/8/2020    Close   00310913
```

Output

```
ColumnA     ColumnB ColumnC
8/26/2020   Approve 00310913
```

Comment: By the date column, i.e `select * where columnb = 'Requeue' order by columnA limit 1'` will get you the most recent

Comment: Thank you, Ive fixed the wording to the first `Requeue` instead of the recent

Comment: Yes. data is only being appended by date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A:C,MATCH("Requeue",B:B,0)-1,3),
  "select Col1,Col2,Col3 
    where Col2='Approve' 
    order by Col1 desc 
    limit 1"
)
```

1. We find the first occurrence of "Requeue", then return the table up to that record
2. Then query, looking for the last occurrence of 'Approve' in Column 2.

Comment: Marking this solution correct aswell as it does it using query, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to obtain the last date of "Approve" before the first (by date) "Requeue" :

```
=MAX(FILTER($A:$A;$B:B="Approve";$A:$A<=MIN(FILTER($A:$A;$B:$B="Requeue"))))
```

And if you know that you want the line before the first "Requeue" you can do :

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(MATCH("Requeue";$B:$B;0)-1)&":C"&(MATCH("Requeue";$B:$B;0)-1))
```